# vscode+node.jsでデバッグをやったら結果の表示がおかしいのは仕様ですか？

Tags: javascript, node.js

vscode+node.jsでjavascriptの練習をやっていました。少し長いコードになりますがこのようなコードを書いていました。

```
var score = [100, 300, 500]
console.log(score[0])

    //配列の値を書き換えるには
    score[2] = 400
    //配列を全て表示するには
    console.log(score)
    //配列は文字列も扱うことができる
    var str = ['taguti', 'sugimoto']
    console.log(str)
    //配列の中に配列を書く
    var m = [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6]
    ]
    console.log(m[1][1])
```

これをみると最後のconsole.log(m[1][1])#5
となると思うのですが、なぜか途中に5が表示されます。line表示はあっていますが、これってかなりわかりにくいと思うんですが、なにかアドバイスいただけないでしょうか？

#### 以下が実行結果です

```
Debugging with inspector protocol because Node.js v8.9.3 was detected.
node --inspect-brk=24044 配列.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:24044/52ad79a6-4f32-453c-a600-e2cd1b2ce596
100
Array(3) [100, 300, 400]
5
Array(2) ["taguti", "sugimoto"]
```

Comment: こちらに記載されているコードだけでは私の環境で再現しないんですよね。気になる点と言えばローカルのWebSocket越しに出力していることなので、`console.log`のアウトプットが非同期になっているのでは？基本的にシングルスレッドな筈なので非同期にならない限り入出力が前後することは考えにくいです。